# recipient name encoding in phpmailer

Tags: php, encoding, gmail, phpmailer

Please I need a help because this problem is really killed me ...
   When I send an Email with PHPMAILER using localhost on Wamp server with a non English text ,The receiver shows the Email as is (The body and subject) but TO name is shows as a numbers and hashes(symboles) , This name  was got from POST[]

Now, if i write a text directly to a variable then it received as is ($variable='Arabic name';) this sends correctly(the name TO is true).
This what i got when getting the name from POST!

```
from:correct in any language<my@gmail.com>
reply-to:   Information <info@example.com>
to: "&#1605;&#1581;&#1605;&#1583;" <my@gmail.com>
```

I don't know why the receiver name is converted to symbols like that.

```
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->Encoding     = "base64";
```

And as i mentioned above ALL Email elements(body,subject and sender name) are correct.

Comment: Good read.  https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2047.txt  RFC specific to some of this and not too long.  Worth it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using [`html_entity_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) to translate that back to a normal string.

```
$normalString = html_entity_decode($_POST['to']);
```